# How can I count the number of days that match between a data frame with two vectors (start date and end date) and a vector of dates?

Tags: r, date

I have a very large data set (>12,000 rows) that contains two vectors of the start and end date of a measurement (relative growth rate). Each row has an individual, the date of the initial measurement, the date of the final measurement, and then the growth rate associated with that window. I want to count the number of days within each growth measurement that match dates that are in a separate vector. So ideally I would be adding a vector to the data frame that gives me a count of the number of matching days between the dates in the df and the external vector for each individual's growth rate.

Sample of what the data frame looks like, but in actuality it is much, much larger

```
individual <- c(1:5)
initialdate <- c("1990-03-01", "1991-05-07", "1992-05-02",
                 "1994-03-02", "1995-03-08")
enddate <- c("1991-08-05", "1993-02-17", "1995-06-22", 
             "1995-09-12", "1997-08-18")
RGR <- c(0.25, 0.3, 0.09, 0.48, 0.34)
df <- data.frame(individual, initialdate, enddate, RGR)

DaysToMatch <- c("1991-03-30", "1993-12-18", ... ) 

countDays <- function(df$initialdate, df$enddate, DaysToMatch) { 
    measurementwindow <- seq(as.Date(initialdate), as.Date(enddate), by="days") 
    commonDays <- length(intersect(measurementwindow, DaysToMatch)) 
    return(commonDays) 
}
```

> Error in seq.Date(as.Date(InitialDate), as.Date(ObsrvnDate), by = "days") : 
>     'from' must be of length 1

I also suspect that I am not indexing the vectors properly to calculate the commonDays for each row of the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert `DaysToMatch` to date and call `countDays` function using `mapply`

```
DaysToMatch <- as.Date(c("1991-03-30", "1993-12-18"))

countDays <- function(initialdate, enddate, DaysToMatch) {
   measurementwindow <- seq(as.Date(initialdate), as.Date(enddate), by="days")
   commonDays <- length(intersect(measurementwindow, DaysToMatch))
   #Or sum(DaysToMatch %in% measurementwindow)
   return(commonDays)
}

df$commonDays <- mapply(countDays, df$initialdate, df$enddate, 
                 MoreArgs = list(DaysToMatch = DaysToMatch))

df
#  individual initialdate    enddate  RGR commonDays
#1          1  1990-03-01 1991-08-05 0.25          1
#2          2  1991-05-07 1993-02-17 0.30          0
#3          3  1992-05-02 1995-06-22 0.09          1
#4          4  1994-03-02 1995-09-12 0.48          0
#5          5  1995-03-08 1997-08-18 0.34          0
```

---

However, we can also use `dplyr::between` to calculate number of values between two boundaries.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Date")), as.Date) %>%
  mutate(commonDays = map2_int(initialdate, enddate, 
                      ~sum(dplyr::between(DaysToMatch, .x, .y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use data.table join in an efficient and compact way

```
library(data.table)
n <-  data.table(date = DaysToMatch)[df, .N, 
      on = .(date > initialdate, date <= enddate), by = .EACHI]$N
df$commonDays <- n
df
#  individual initialdate    enddate  RGR commonDays
#1          1  1990-03-01 1991-08-05 0.25          1
#2          2  1991-05-07 1993-02-17 0.30          0
#3          3  1992-05-02 1995-06-22 0.09          1
#4          4  1994-03-02 1995-09-12 0.48          0
#5          5  1995-03-08 1997-08-18 0.34          0
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(commonDays = sum(between(DaysToMatch, initialdate, enddate)))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  individual initialdate enddate      RGR commonDays
#       <int> <date>      <date>     <dbl>      <int>
#1          1 1990-03-01  1991-08-05  0.25          1
#2          2 1991-05-07  1993-02-17  0.3           0
#3          3 1992-05-02  1995-06-22  0.09          1
#4          4 1994-03-02  1995-09-12  0.48          0
#5          5 1995-03-08  1997-08-18  0.34          0
```

#### data

```
df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], as.Date)
DaysToMatch <- as.Date(c("1991-03-30", "1993-12-18"))
```